# Substitute env_file values with .env values on docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables

Is it possible to substitute (without the use of external tools like `envsubst`) values in an environment file used in docker-compose (using `env_file`) with values on a `.env` file in the folder?

Say I have this `.env` file:

```
REGISTRY=something
TAG=something-else
```

Now in my `docker-compose.yml` I can have:

```yaml
# ...
   my_service:
      environment:
        - USE_IMAGE:${REGISTRY}/my_image:${TAG}
# ...
```

What I'd like is having a different environment file (say, `myservice.env`), like this:

```
USE_IMAGE=${REGISTRY}/my_image:${TAG}
```

And use it on the compose file like:

```yaml
# ...
   my_service:
      env_file:
        - myservice.env
# ...
```

However by default, docker-compose (which is the one reading the .env file) doesn't seem to be substituting anything on the other files and I get the literal value.

Is there a way to do this without requiring to have a "rendered" file, directly with docker compose?

I understand I could make a script to pre-process those files using `envsubst` or something similar, but I'm trying to find a solution without that

Comment: Your myservice.env file must be in the format of KEY=VALUE.  That still may not give you what you want, https://stackoverflow.com/q/37926473/8254477 is an alternative pattern that works quite well.

Comment: @swysocki oh yes, sorry, that was a typo... corrected. I'll check your link, thanks